# The dataframe values used to create the GeoTIFF and the values extracted from GeoTIFF are not matching

Tags: python, raster, geotiff-tiff, geopandas, rasterio

I have created a GeoTIFF file using the code below.

**Part1**: code for GeoTIFF creation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rasterio as rio

# Define the range of latitudes and longitudes
lat_range = (39, 41)
lon_range = (-76, -73)

# Define the resolution of the grid
resolution = 0.1

# Create arrays of the latitude and longitude values
lats = np.arange(lat_range[0], lat_range[1], resolution)
lons = np.arange(lon_range[0], lon_range[1], resolution)

# Create a meshgrid of the latitude and longitude values
lon_mesh, lat_mesh = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

# Flatten the meshgrids into 1D arrays of latitude and longitude values
lat_values = lat_mesh.flatten()
lon_values = lon_mesh.flatten()

# Generate random z values for each latitude and longitude pair
z_values = np.random.rand(len(lat_values))

# Create a pandas DataFrame to store the data
data = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat_values, 'lon': lon_values, 'z': z_values})

# Define the GeoTIFF file parameters
width = len(lons)
height = len(lats)
transform = rio.transform.from_bounds(lon_range[0], lat_range[0], lon_range[1], lat_range[1], width, height)
crs = rio.crs.CRS.from_epsg(4326)  # WGS 1984

# Write the GeoTIFF file
with rio.open("output.tif", "w", driver="GTiff", width=width, height=height, count=1, dtype=np.float32, nodata=0, transform=transform, crs=crs) as dst:
    # Reshape the z values into a 2D array and write them to the GeoTIFF file
    z_array = z_values.reshape((height, width))
    dst.write(z_array, 1)
```

Then used the following code to extract the values from the above geotiff file stored as output.tif.

**Part2**: code for extraction.

```
import rasterio as rio
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

# Load the GeoTIFF file
with rio.open(r"E:\\Machine_Learning_for_Himalaya_IEEE_GRSL\\plots\\output.tif") as src:
    # Extract the metadata for the file
    meta = src.meta
    print("meta:",meta)
    # Define the latitude and longitude ranges
    lat_range = (39, 41)
    lon_range = (-76, -73)

    # Create a grid of points with a 0.1 degree interval within the specified ranges
    lats = np.arange(lat_range[0], lat_range[1], 0.1)
    lons = np.arange(lon_range[0], lon_range[1], 0.1)
    lon_mesh, lat_mesh = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
    geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(lon_mesh.ravel(), lat_mesh.ravel())
    points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geometry)

    # Extract the z values at the point locations using rasterio.sample
    zs = list(src.sample(zip(points.geometry.x, points.geometry.y)))

    # Create a Pandas DataFrame to store the point coordinates and values
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude': lat_mesh.ravel(),
                       'Longitude': lon_mesh.ravel(),
                       'Value': zs})

print(df)
```

The outputs are as follows:
for the second part following is output:

```
meta: {'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': 0.0, 'width': 30, 'height': 20, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(4326), 'transform': Affine(0.1, 0.0, -76.0,
       0.0, -0.1, 41.0)}
     Latitude  Longitude        Value
0        39.0      -76.0        [0.0]
1        39.0      -75.9        [0.0]
2        39.0      -75.8        [0.0]
3        39.0      -75.7        [0.0]
4        39.0      -75.6        [0.0]
..        ...        ...          ...
595      40.9      -73.5  [0.5188609]
596      40.9      -73.4   [0.589194]
597      40.9      -73.3  [0.5691334]
598      40.9      -73.2  [0.8172998]
599      40.9      -73.1  [0.5687353]

[600 rows x 3 columns]
```

If we print the dataframe i.e., data from the Part1 code, the output is as below.

```
      lat   lon         z
0    39.0 -76.0  0.613836
1    39.0 -75.9  0.002668
2    39.0 -75.8  0.432013
3    39.0 -75.7  0.912882
4    39.0 -75.6  0.892871
..    ...   ...       ...
595  40.9 -73.5  0.170039
596  40.9 -73.4  0.340669
597  40.9 -73.3  0.809385
598  40.9 -73.2  0.501880
599  40.9 -73.1  0.085377

[600 rows x 3 columns]
```

We can clearly see the values are different for same coordinates in the above outputs. How to sort this and why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your points are falling exactly on the corners of the pixels.

[image]

If you offset them by half a pixel in the x & y dimension, you'll get the right answer.

```
    # Create a grid of points with a 0.1 degree interval within the specified ranges
    lats = np.arange(lat_range[0], lat_range[1], 0.1) + 0.05  # offset by 1/2 pixel
    lons = np.arange(lon_range[0], lon_range[1], 0.1) + 0.05
```

[image]